# AS3...instantiating movieclips from library and also creating them dynamically...is stop() needed?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

In the past, we've put a stop() action in the timeline of movieclip symbols so that the timeline would not play and we would control all animations via code.

We've also done that to the main timeline as well.

Is this still needed for performance reasons? Is this needed for dynamically created movieclips?

I know that the Sprite class should be used if there is no timeline associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this. When you create your instance, if your movieClip has more than one frame simply call stop on that instance:

```
 var ball:MovieClip = new Ball();
 ball.stop();
 addChild(ball);
```